# How to set time as local (IST) time?

Tags: sql-server

I have a script where it is taking time as UTC (GMT). To run the script every time I have to put GMT timings. But I want to insert my local time so that it would convert to GMT automatically and fetch me the result.

Declare @baseline_start_time  time = NULL

Set @baseline_start_time =''

Comment: So do you want local time or GMT time? It is not clear. local time = getdate(), GMT time = getutcdate()

Comment: The script was written to accept only GMT timings. But my system generates timestamp using sysDate and sysTime i.e. IST. So I will put IST timings and it should automatically change to UTC.

Comment: Just use getutcdate. That is what it is for. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178635.aspx